# How to pass nested list element to the controller in spring mvc

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

In my jsp page there have a table with nested list value, i want to send that table value to the container, The outer table value were sent but the inner table value not sent to the container, I am new here please let me know how to over come this situation,

My jsp

```
<script>
function rowAdded(rowElement) {
    //clear the imput fields for the row
    $(rowElement).find("input").val('');
    //may want to reset <select> options etc

    //in fact you may want to submit the form
    saveNeeded();
}
function rowRemoved(rowElement) {
    saveNeeded();
}
function saveNeeded() {
    $('#submit').css('color','red');
    $('#submit').css('font-weight','bold');
    if( $('#submit').val().indexOf('!') != 0 ) {
        $('#submit').val( '!' + $('#submit').val() );
    }
}
function beforeSubmit() {
    alert('script Working');
    return true;
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    var config = {
        rowClass : 'rule',
        addRowId : 'addRule',
        removeRowClass : 'removeRule',
        formId : 'ruleListForm',
        rowContainerId : 'ruleListContainer',
        indexedPropertyName : 'ruleList',
        indexedPropertyMemberNames : 'id,ruleName,parameterName,overwriteValue',
        rowAddedListener : rowAdded,
        rowRemovedListener : rowRemoved,
        beforeSubmit : beforeSubmit
    };
    new DynamicListHelper(config);
});
</script>
<html>
<form:form action="/update" method="post" id="ruleListForm"   modelAttribute="ruleListContainer">

            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <h3 align="center">Selected Rule</h3>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="id" width="25">ID&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  </th>
                        <th data-field="details" width="20">RuleName&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>

                        <th data-field="parameter" width="240">Parameter&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="ruleListContainer">
                    <c:forEach items="${List2}" var="as">

                        <tr class="rule">
                            <td><input type="hidden" name="ruleList[].id" value="${as.rule.id}" /> ${as.rule.id}</td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" name="ruleList[].ruleName" value="${as.rule.ruleName}" /> ${as.rule.ruleName}</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;<input id="one" class="datepicker" type="text" name="ruleList[].startDate" size="11" height="0.10"></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;<input id="two" class="datepicker" type="text" name="ruleList[].endDate" size="11" height="0.10"></td>
                            <td>
                                <table border="1">
                                    <c:forEach items="${as.ruleAssignmentParameter}" var="asss">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type="hidden" name="ruleList[].parameterName"value="${asss.parameterName}" > ${asss.parameterName}</td>
                                            <td><input type="hidden" name="ruleList[].overwriteValue" value="${asss.overwriteValue}" /> ${asss.overwriteValue}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br>
             <input type="submit" value="Update">
        </form:form>
</html>
```

Here is my model class

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import com.demo.app.model.RuleAssignmentParameter;
public class RuleAssUI {
private int id;
private String ruleName;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getRuleName() {
    return ruleName;
}
public void setRuleName(String ruleName) {
    this.ruleName = ruleName;
}
private List<RuleAssignmentParameter> ruleAssignmentParameter = new LinkedList<RuleAssignmentParameter>();

public List<RuleAssignmentParameter> getRuleAssignmentParameter() {
    return ruleAssignmentParameter;
}
public void setRuleAssignmentParameter(List<RuleAssignmentParameter> ruleAssignmentParameter) {
    this.ruleAssignmentParameter = ruleAssignmentParameter;
}
public RuleAssUI(){     
}
public RuleAssUI(int id,String ruleName){
    this.id=id;
    this.ruleName=ruleName; 
}
}
```

My container where i store the list value

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
public class RuleListContainer {
 private List<RuleAssUI> ruleList = new LinkedList<RuleAssUI>();
    public RuleListContainer() {
    }

    public RuleListContainer(List<RuleAssUI> ruleList) {
        this.ruleList = ruleList;
    }

    public List<RuleAssUI> getRuleList() {
        return ruleList;
    }

    public void setRuleList(List<RuleAssUI> ruleList) {
        this.ruleList = ruleList;
    }
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") RuleListContainer ruleListContainer, HttpSession session, ModelMap model) {

    ruleListContainer.getRuleList().size();

    for (RuleAssUI rul1 : ruleListContainer.getRuleList()) {
        System.out.println("Id:   " + rul1.getId());
        System.out.println("RuleName:  " + rul1.getRuleName());
        for (RuleAssignmentParameter rul2 : rul1.getRuleAssignmentParameter()) {
            System.out.println("ParameterName: " + rul2.getParameterName());
            System.out.println("ParameterValue: " + rul2.getOverwriteValue());

        }
    }
    session.setAttribute("ruleListContainer", ruleListContainer);
    return "hello";
}
```

I am trying so many time but unable to fixed the issue, And browse also but did't get any proper help, so please help to do items

I NEED HELP PLEASE SOME BODY HELP ME...!

Thank you in advance

Comment: where comes from this list? <c:forEach items="${List2}" var="as">

Comment: @cralfaro, There have one ruleassignment details class from this class i create that List2

Comment: @cralfaro, i am able to populate the list and nested list value form database, which is hold in  List2, But problem is that when i send this value to the controller it is not pass.

Comment: i response you in an answer will be easier to read there.

Comment: let me know if adding indexes fixed your problem

Comment: @ cralfaro, ok i will inform you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your jsp file.
You need to set the index of each list element.

```
<c:forEach items="${List2}" var="as" varStatus="vs">

                    <tr class="rule">
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="ruleList[${vs.index}].id" value="${as.rule.id}" /> ${as.rule.id}</td>
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="ruleList[${vs.index}].ruleName" value="${as.rule.ruleName}" /> ${as.rule.ruleName}</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;<input id="one" class="datepicker" type="text" name="ruleList[${vs.index}].startDate" size="11" height="0.10"></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;<input id="two" class="datepicker" type="text" name="ruleList[${vs.index}].endDate" size="11" height="0.10"></td>
                        <td>
                            <table border="1">
                                <c:forEach items="${as.ruleAssignmentParameter}" var="asss" varStatus="assignments">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="hidden" name="ruleList[${vs.index}].ruleAssignmentParameter[${assignments.index}].parameterName" value="${asss.parameterName}" > ${asss.parameterName}</td>
                                        <td><input type="hidden" name="ruleList[${vs.index}].ruleAssignmentParameter[${assignments.index}].overwriteValue" value="${asss.overwriteValue}" /> ${asss.overwriteValue}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
```

Also in your controller (POST method) you are trying to get the object identified by "SpringWeb" but should be "ruleListContainer", same name you have in your form tag

The problem was you had a list into RuleAssUI and you was not accesing correctly, you need 2 loops and indexes, one for each list.

Here is the key:

```
ruleList[${vs.index}].ruleAssignmentParameter[${assignments.index}].parameterName
```

Comment: @ cralfaro, Still is not working, the parameterName & overwriteValue not pass to the container actuly

Comment: @ cralfaro, after adding indexes nothing is happen, still the value is not pass to the container, what i do sir.? i am trying thousand of time but still unable to fi the problem

Comment: @Emad also be sure the name of the object you are using in your form tag is the same in your POST method with the ModelAttribute

Comment: @ cralfaro, yes it is same

Comment: The id and ruleName are pass to the container, i can see the list value, by setting debugging point in update servlet, but the parameterName and Overwritevalue were null,

Comment: When i debug i seen the list is retrieve in  rulelistcontainer, with id and ruleName, inside this container another list ruleAssignment parameter is retrieve but the element(parameterName,overwriteValue) are not .

Comment: @Emad I edited my response, but the problem seems, the attributes parameterName and overwriteValue are not inside RuleAssUI, and according to the JSP, is where you are expecting to find it. Add those attribues to your class and will work

Comment: @ cralfaro, What ever you said, please could you add in your answer please, it will be easier for me to understand, and thank you so much for your kind help sir, i am facing this problem from last 3 days,

Comment: @ cralfaro, very sad to say sir, i did same to same what ever told by you, but its still same as the previous situation, Problem in my jsp actually, the parameterName, overwrite values are not pass to the container

Comment: @Emad did you inspect the request sent to the controller? appears the attributes with a wrong name? doesn't appears?

Comment: @ cralfaro, Sir Any other way to do this..?? Every thing is fine one that logic, but i don't understand why value is not pass to the container,

Comment: @Emad could you share here your email and i can check the code and see what could be?

Comment: @ cralfaro, I did it, Thank you so much sir, for your kind help, i highly appreciate your help , Thank you again

Comment: @Emad sorry but i cant find your email account in the comments

Comment: @ cralfaro, Sorry i forgot to mention, My Email id- emad.rahman1991@gmail.com, ping me on my mail id.